# ERROR #1111 - Utilisation invalide de la clause GROUP

Tags: mysql, sql

I search for the rank of a student by entering two tables from my database first we have the grades table (id, marks, student_id, course_id) then we have the races table (id, name, coef) to find the toral of the averages of a student we use the SUM (grades.marks*courses.coef) and now we would like to know the rank of each students as a function of averages

here is the request used

```
SELECT g1.student_id, SUM(g1.marks*c.coef) as averages1, 
        (SELECT COUNT(SUM(g2.marks*c2.coef))+1
        FROM grades g2 
            JOIN courses c2 ON c2.id = g2.course_id
        HAVING SUM(g1.marks*c.coef) < SUM(g2.marks*c2.coef)
        ) AS RANG
FROM grades g1 
    JOIN courses c ON c.id = g1.course_id
GROUP BY g1.student_id
ORDER BY averages1 DESC
```

Comment: You cannot aggregate by external table in correlated subquery.

Comment: I did not understand soyer a little clearer please

Comment: You use an expression `SUM(g1.marks*c.coef)` in the subquery. This aggregate expression uses the columns which are external for the subquery. This is not allowed.

Comment: what can I do to remedy it

Comment: I add an INNER JOIN that displays but at the level of the rank it counts the elements of the two table so replace the HAVING by the WHERE but it always sends me the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ranking, use the `rank()` function:

```
SELECT g.student_id, SUM(g.marks * c.coef) as averages,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY  SUM(g.marks*c.coef) DESC) as ranking
FROM grades g JOIN
     courses c
     ON c.id = g1.course_id
GROUP BY g.student_id
ORDER BY averages DESC
```

Comment: desolated it does not work  it sends me back this error Syntax error near 'OVER (ORDER BY SUM(g.marks*c.coef) DESC)) AS ranking
FROM grades g JOIN

Comment: @NickNicklaus . . . MySQL has supported `RANK()` since 8.0 was released over three years ago.